# Why do database changes only show in the current cursor?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am inserting a row into my table and while I select data from it using the same cursor, it works fine. But when I try view it by other means or create a new cursor, it seems to magically disappear. Here is what I mean:

```
>>> cur = MySQLdb.connect(user='alex', db='testing').cursor()
>>> target = 'Alex'
>>> cur.execute("""INSERT INTO user_data (nick, points) VALUES (%s, 100);""", (target.lower()))
1L
>>> cur.execute("""SELECT points FROM user_data WHERE nick = %s;""", (target.lower()))
1L
>>> total = str(cur.fetchone()[0])
>>> print total
100
>>> cur = MySQLdb.connect(user='alex', db='testing').cursor()
>>> cur.execute("""SELECT points FROM user_data WHERE nick = %s;""", (target.lower()))
0L
>>> total = str(cur.fetchone()[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>>
```

Can anyone tell me why MySQLdb is doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that your problem is that you're not committing your transaction. Try to call `commit()` after your insert.

That is, you have to do

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='alex', db='testing')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO user_data (nick, points) VALUES (%s, 100);""", (target.lower()))
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 3):

See info on auto-commit:  http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#my-data-disappeared-or-won-t-go-away

Answer (score 1):

You should read about [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), which is supported by MySQL when using InnoDB for example.

What you're experiencing is the [Isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) property: your two connections have opened two distinct transactions (by doing this `MySQLdb.connect(user='alex', db='testing').cursor()` twice, you're doing more than creating two cursors, you're creating two connections too). You'd need to commit a transaction before opening a new one if you want the changes to be visible in subsequent transactions.

It's also generally worth reading the [chapter on InnoDB's transaction model](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-transaction-model.html) (or the one for the engine you're using).